# While loop in c++ cannot exit

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have this code, its just a part from another bigger code. This may seem like a very simple mistake, but I still cannot figure out what it is. My problem is that the value of 'house1' cannot exit the while loop and move on to switch statement. for example, if I entered house1 = 0, the program will print "Invalid value, please enter again" but if I entered house1 = 1 after I enter the invalid value,  it will also print "invalid value, please enter again". Does anyone have any idea what was my mistake?

```
cin >> house1 ;
while ((0 <= house1) || (house1 >= 6))
{
    cout << "Invalid value! please enter again:";
    cin >> house1;
}
switch (house1)
{
case '1':
    h1_p1 = h1_p1 - 5;
    h2_p1 = h2_p1 + 1;
    h3_p1 = h3_p1 + 1;
    h4_p1 = h4_p1 + 1;
    h5_p1 = h5_p1 + 1;
    house_p1 = house_p1 + 1;
    break;
case '2':
    h2_p1 = h2_p1 - 5;
    h3_p1 = h3_p1 + 1;
    h4_p1 = h4_p1 + 1;
    h5_p1 = h5_p1 + 1;
    house_p1 = house_p1 + 2;
    break;
```

Comment: `0 <= house1` i think this one is inverted. because 0 is <= 1 so it'll ask you again. *also* `case '1'` and `case 1` isnt the same thing. your while loop condition is checking for the integral value 1, but your case statement is checking the integral value of the *character* 1.

Comment: Read the condition in the `while` statement carefully. What does it do when `house1` is equal to 0? (also, note that the two sets of parentheses around the two comparisons in that statement are redundant)

Comment: I believe you want `(house1 <= 0)` rather than `(0 <= house1)`.

Comment: oh i see, thanks i have figure it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant the valid value should be from `1` to `5`, the condition should be

```
while ((house1 <= 0) || (house1 >= 6))
{
    cout << "Invalid value! please enter again:";
    cin >> house1;
}
```

BTW: You're not checking invalid input (the [failbit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) of `cin`) for `house1`.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with this code is this statement

```
while ((0 <= house1) || (house1 >= 6))
```

See if you enter `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...` or any positive integer number (as the value of house1) this while statement is correct for that.

So the control goes into the while loop and will not come out of the loop until you enter the negative number... Because when you enter the negative number only then the condition in the while statement will not satisfy and the control will come out of the loop.